# Load xml into excel with formula definition

Tags: xml, excel, excel-formula, vba

I am importing xml file into excel this way

```
ActiveWorkbook.XmlImport url:=dataurl, importMap:=Nothing, overwrite:=True, Destination:=Range("MYSheet!A1")
```

Works fine and seemed to be effective, but I would like to load some of columns as calculation, so when user change column 1, it should also effect column 3 because column 3 has formula using relative column index `=SUM(R[-3]C,R[-2]C)`. Unfortunately during export/import of xml, xsd of appropriate XmlMap all values are converted into string. Is it possible to define excel xsd in a way, that the column be recognized as formula ?

I tried searching for solution in google but didn't find any. Is that even possible? I know that I could setup formulas after load, but I am loading huge dataset and would like to save some time.